# PHP - MySQL query without speech marks

Tags: php, mysql

```
$queryDetails = mysql_query("SELECT * from members WHERE username = '$current_url' ");
```

I'm trying to use `fwrite` to create a page on register. This is the only thing what is going wrong. As I'm using 'fwrite', I cannot use speech marks as it ends the 'fwrite' command. 

I've tried escaping the query out;

```
$queryDetails = mysql_query('SELECT * from members WHERE username = \'$current_url\' ');
```

But that hasn't worked. I can't use " as it closes the `fwrite`. 
Any help?

The full code is

```
$queryDetails = mysql_query('SELECT * from members WHERE username = \'$current_url\' ');
$queryNumRowsDetails = @mysql_num_rows($queryDetails);

if ($queryNumRowsDetails != 0){

    //collect data from SQL database
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryDetails)){
        $dbUsername = $row['username'];
        $dbClub = $row['club'];
        $dbReputation = $row['reputation'];
    }

}
else{
    die("There was a problem gathering user data.");
}
```

And if I try to escape the ' as shown in the second code block. It goes to the "There was a problem gathering user data."

$current_url is a variable collecting the current URL and taking away a few bits, leaving only a username remaining. Meaning example.com/users/AdziHades/index.php equates to just AdziHades.

Comment: @AdziHades - your code doesn't use fwrite at all. What, exactly, is the issue? Are you trying to write that PHP to a file, or something?

Comment: The Fwrite is on register. So as it registers a user. It uses Fwrite to create a user page. This code is in the user page and is essential for gathering information such as the 'reputation' value.

Comment: @AdziHades - you can get the same effect in a couple of different ways - you can use .htaccess to have a single page, but make it look like everyone has their own page, for example. If you do need to do this, then I suggest you look at using HEREDOC syntax: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Comment: I need it so people can go to example.com/users/AdziHades and it shows their profile.
 So I currently mkdir /users/$username and then fwrite in connect.php & index.php 
That way the URL example.com/users/AdziHades shows index.php, which is the profile of that user. There's probably hundreds of easier ways but this is the only one I know of current :)

Comment: We need to know how `$current_url` is defined/used and what's being passed in there. You may need to use `stripslashes()` and/or  `mysql_real_escape_string()` since URL's consist of characters that SQL may not like unless they are escaped.

Comment: $current_url is just the current URL minus a few parts. In this case, it just displays the username from example.com/users/username

Comment: It is totally bad idea creating folders and pages for per user.

Comment: It's the only way I know currently. Haha.

Comment: You haven't answered my question. Current URL contains `//` and a dot etc., correct? Show me an actual example. In doing that, SQL throws an error. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and you'll see what I mean, since you may not be checking for errors. As well as `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`

Comment: $current_url, in this case, equates to simply "AdziHades"...

    $currentUrl = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];  
    $site = rtrim($currentUrl, 'index.php/');  
    $current_url = str_replace('/login/users/', '', $site);

Comment: `var_dump($queryDetails);` right after your query and you'll see what's being passed through. See my other comment just above concerning error reporting. You can debug from there.

Comment: It works fine standalone. It's just because I have to 'fwrite' it to another file. I cannot use speech marks.

Comment: You'll need to show us the code (or full code) that you're using for `fwrite` then. Have you not used any of my suggestions?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60782/discussion-on-question-by-adzihades-php-mysql-query-without-speech-marks).

Answer (score 0):

Though your question lacks the information indicating what's not working, it looks like your problem with the query might be that you're using single quotes and trying to have it evaluate the variable inside. For example:

```
$myvar = 2;
$mystring = "I have $myvar apples.";
```

In that code, `$mystring` would evaluate to `I have 2 apples.`. If, instead, you use single quotes, like so:

```
$myvar = 2;
$mystring = 'I have $myvar apples.';
```

You will get `I have $myvar apples.'`. This is because single quotes will not evaluate variables automatically. Note: I am NOT referring to the quotes used in the query itself (around `$current_url`), I'm talking about the quotes around the entire query.

You have two options here. The 'easy' option is to just concatenate the value of the variable. The better, more future-proof way is to switch to using prepared statements with `PDO` ([here is a page that explains why you should be using this and how to use it](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) or at least `mysqli`. Prepared statements will allow for more secure queries without you having to manually escape your values to prevent SQL injection. I **highly** recommend you look at going down this route. The mysql_* extensions you're using have been deprecated and will most likely cause you problems in the future.